# How to get localport using java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

The following code returns -1.Please any body tell solution to solve and tell something about this uses of localport .

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        int i = s.getLocalPort();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you read the documentation first ?

Comment: Socket is not bound yet?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getLocalPort()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Socket` created by `new Socket()` doesn't have a local port until you either `bind()` or `connect()` it.